# Find User in Mongo DB and then update the field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an authentication link which is sent by the company to their team member to allow them access to join.

Currently, my logic is looking something like this - with a bit of semi-code.

Firstly, I have two schema's, one for company and one for user.

```
const CompanyProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        companyTitle:{type:String, required: true, unique: true, default: ""},
        companyPassword:{type:String, required: true, default: ""},
        centralEmail:{type:String, required: true, unique: true, default: ""},
        description:{type:String, required: true, default: ""},
        inviteToken:{type:String, required: true, default:""},
        industry:{type:String, required: true},
        employees:{type: Number},
        companyImage: {type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        locationCity:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        industry:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        country:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        teamMembers: {
            type: String, required: true, default: 0
        },
        teamMemberDetails: {
            memberName: [String], default: [],
            memberEmail: [String], default: [],
            memberRole: [String], default: []
        },
        highlights: {type: Array},
        isAdmin:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isVerified:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        accountLevel: {type: Array},
        emailAuthorised: { type: Boolean, default: false},
        invitedUsers: {type: Array}
    },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("CompanyUser", CompanyProfileSchema)


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        //userdetails
        username: {type: String, required: true, default: "" },
        password:{type:String, required: true},
        //profile
        fullname:{type:String, required: false, default: "none"},
        firstname:{type:String, required: false, default: "", unique: false},
        surname:{type:String, required: false, default: "", unique: false},
        email:{type:String, required: true, unique: true},
        position: {type:String, required: false, unique: false},
        recruiter: {type: Boolean}, //Canidate or Recruiter,
        userImage: {type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        //location
        locationCity:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        country:{type:String, required: false, unique: false, default: ""},
        //work
        role:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        company: {type:String, default: ""},
        emailAuthorised: { type: Boolean, default: false},
        professionalBio: {type:String, default: ""},
        positionRecentTitle : {type:String, default: ""},
        positionRecentCompany : {type:String, default: ""},
        companyAuthorised: {type: String, default: ""},
        isAdmin:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    {timestamps: true }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

I have create an API endpoint which sends out an email with the auth token of the company.
I would like to firstly find the user in the DB and update the field 'companyAuthorised' with the userToken of the company.

Secondly, I'd also like to find the company with the token also and update their teamMemberDetails.Email to be the email in the endpoint.

I have created some psuedo code which I think is pretty close, can anyone clarify?

```
  router.get('/inviteToJoinTeam/:token/:email', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      //verify the token against DB
      const userToken = (req.params.token)
      const indivEmailAdd = (req.params.email)

      // creating user auth
      try{
        const userDetails = await User.find({email: indivEmailAdd})
        const { password, ...others } = userDetails._doc;
        const userID = userDetails.id

        const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userID, { companyAuthorised: {userToken}});

      }catch{
        console.log('failure')
      }

      // creating company auth
      try{
        const companyDetails = await CompanyUser.find({inviteToken: userToken})
        const { password, ...others } = companyDetails._doc;
        const companyID = companyDetails.id

        const updateCompany = await CompanyUser.findByIdAndUpdate(companyID, { teamMemberDetails.memberEmail: {indivEmailAdd}});

      }catch{
        console.log('failure')
      }
      console.log('successfully completed try')
      res.send('final')
  
    } catch (e) {
      res.send('This isnt working');
    }
  
  });
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your use case, the code you are looking to write would be the following:

```js
router.get('/inviteToJoinTeam/:token/:email', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //verify the token against DB
    const userToken = req.params.token;
    const indivEmailAdd = req.params.email;

    // creating user auth
    try {
      const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email: indivEmailAdd },
        { companyAuthorised: userToken },
      ).lean();
    } catch {
      console.log('failure');
    }

    // creating company auth
    try {
      const updatedCompany = await CompanyUser.findOneAndUpdate(
        { inviteToken: userToken },
        {
          'teamMemberDetails.memberEmail': indivEmailAdd,
        },
      ).lean();
    } catch {
      console.log('failure');
    }
    console.log('successfully completed try');
    res.send('final');
  } catch (e) {
    res.send('This isnt working');
  }
});
```